# NoSuchFileException in JAR file with Playwright

Tags: java, jar, playwright

My java spring-boot service works excellent from IDE Idea, but it fails with exception when I try to execute jar file:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /BOOT-INF/lib/driver-bundle-0.180.0.jar!/driver/linux
```

I'm using Playwright library in my dependencies which has such code:

```
    private void extractDriverToTempDir() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URI uri = classloader.getResource("driver/" + platformDir()).toURI();
```

I found that **getResource()** causes this exception, but I'm not sure that it is my case.

Please, how can I run my jar file correctly or find the reason of such exception?

Comment: What  `platformDir()` looks like and where do you store this file?

Comment: @Flame239 it is not my code. i use dependency in my project. [to github](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-java/blob/90940b23f3b37fa82377a0aec8fa04359bed4286/driver-bundle/src/main/java/com/microsoft/playwright/impl/DriverJar.java#L58)

Comment: Seems like a duplicate and already triaged on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-java/issues/263 the issue with host dependencies occurs because not all dependencies which are required to start a browser are installed.